# Using and Verifying DNSSEC with DNS server

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, security, dns

On a machine running Windows that is configured to use a DNS server that supports [DNSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions), what is the easiest way to verify DNS SEC is infact being used?

Answer (score 0):

DNSSEC Resolver Test (http://dnssec.vs.uni-due.de).  This test determines whether your DNS resolver validates DNSSEC signatures. For this test you need JavaScript turned on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.